# How to create set of pointers with unique values

Tags: c++, set, unique

Let's say i have a class defined as follows

```
class Foo {
private:
    int date;
    std::string name;

public:
    void setName(std::string a_name){ name = a_name; };
    std::string getName(){ return name; };
    void setDate(int a_date){ date = a_date; }
    int getDate(){ return date; };

    struct FooComparator
    {
        bool operator()(Foo* lhs, Foo* rhs) const { return lhs->getDate() < rhs->getDate(); }
    };
}
```

Now I want to create several objects `Foo` and put them in a set ordered by date so i do

```
std::set<Foo *, Foo::FooComparator> entries;

Foo *a = new Foo();
a->setName("A_OBJ");
a->setDate(10);

entries.insert(a);

Foo *b = new Foo();
b->setName("B_OBJ");
a->setDate(1);

entries.insert(b);

Foo *a_2 = new Foo();
a_2->setName("A_OBJ");
a_2->setDate(9);

entries.insert(a_2);
```

So here is the problem, after this in my set I have 3 entries ordered by `date` since the uniqueness is checked on the pointer value. Is there a way to give the `set` a custom equality comparator so that it will not insert `a_2` since there already is an entry with that name?

I know it is possible with `unordered_set` to pass a custom hash function but I can't seem to find a similar way to do it with `set` and since I need the entries to be unique and sorted `unordered_set` is not an option.

Comment: Your `operator()` should take the parameters as constant reference.  Pointers can point to anywhere, while references are guaranteed to refer to an object.

Comment: Change your `operator()` to compare names, too?

Comment: You don't need to dynamically allocate objects in order to place them into a `std::set`.  The set insert operation will insert a copy.  You are inserting **copies** of pointers into your sets.  Search the internet for "memory leak".

Comment: You can wrap `FooComparator` with a lambda specific for your `std::set` if you are not allowed to directly touch `FooComparator`

Comment: AFAIK, what you want can only be done in the unordered container.  You'd have to wrap it in your own wrapper to provide that extra functionality.  I have to ask, is there are reason you are using a `set<Foo*>` instead of just a `set<Foo>`?

Comment: Perhaps what you want is a map instead?

Comment: Before inserting a_2 in the set, check to see if "A_OBJ" name is already in the set.

Comment: For a `set`, the uniqueness/equivalence relation and the ordering relation must be "the same". That's just a consequence of the (intended) implementation as a binary search tree. If your `set` is ordered by date, then it won't help you enforce uniqueness by name (other than, as @Eljay notes, letting you iterate over all the `Foo`s to see if the name is taken before you insert). If you need the name uniqueness check to be fast, perhaps try using two `set`s, one of names and one of `Foo`s (sorted by date), where you check/update the former before/as you insert into the latter?

Comment: @NathanOliver unfortunately this code was not originally written by me and I can't change the type of the set (at least not without changing an absurd number of dependent code and make many people in my company quite angry)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That seems like the easiest solution but i'm not allowed to change the `set<Foo *>`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that is not a problem, the code isn't exactly like the one i have (I can't share it verbatim due to company policies, but I still think this qualifies as a minimal reproducible example with respect to my question) but i'm certain that the pointer will always be used and deleted only from the set, besides as i've written in other comments changing the `set` type is unfortunately not an option

Comment: @Eljay I guess that could be an option, I was just wondering if there was a way to do it "automagically" and avoid the comparison loop

Answer (score -2):

For sets, equality of `a` and `b` is defined as `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`. You should change your comparator function to reflect that:

```
bool operator()(Foo* lhs, Foo* rhs) const {
    if (lhs->getName() == rhs->getName()) {
        return false;
    }
    return lhs->getDate() < rhs->getDate();
}
```

Comment: This is not allowed. E.g. we get `("A", 5) < ("B", 6)` and `("B", 6) < ("A", 7)`, which should give us `("A", 5) < ("A", 7)`, but that doesn't hold. This "ordering" is therefore invalid, is not a valid argument to `std::set`, and causes UB when used as such. Operationally, there's simply no way to implement `std::set` such that the OP's desired behavior could be encoded in the comparison and the set still has all the nice `O(log n)` properties it's specified to have.

Comment: Here we go: even discounting the UB, [using a comparator like this simply doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/xdYv8W).